# Слишком хорошие результаты на тестовых данных нейросети

Tags: python, keras

Вопрос- полносвязный персептрон на определенном наборе и тренировочных и тестовых данных, в начале обучения быстро растет точность на проверочной выборке, намного превосходя точность на тренировочных данных. На этом наборе данных описанная картина повторяется(не зависит от начального распределения весов). Далее в процессе обучения тестовые результаты ухудшаются, становятся меньше тренировочных. Тестовые данные 20% от конца выборки, всего порядка 1600 экземпляров.

```
   `model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu", name="layer1", input_dim=nimp))    
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation="relu", name="layer2"))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid", name="layer3"))
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0005),            
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])`
```

Мне это не понятно, подскажите, с чем может быть связано такое поведение?
Возможно это перекос суммы датасета:

```
 sum(np.sum(indata_test,axis=1)*t_test[:,1])/np.sum(t_test[:,1],axis=0)
 11.390132806644177
 sum(np.sum(indata_test,axis=1)*t_test[:,0])/np.sum(t_test[:,0],axis=0)
 12.654423331070447
```

[image: Графики сглажены y[i] = y[i-1] + (y - y[i-1])/20]

Comment: Покажите графики обучения, ну или хотя бы логи. Хотя без конкретных данных это всё-равно будет абстрактно всё.

Comment: Если смотреть на график, то вы же видите, какие значения по вертикальной шкале? Ну да, есть некоторые выбросы, но в целом разница между значениями тренировки и валидации на последней эпохе, т.е. между 0.52 и 0.51 - всего 2%, это ерунда вообще. А на максимальном расхождении, т.е. между 0.53 и 0.5 (примерно эпоха 175) - 6%. Если вас именно этот график смутил, то поставьте лимит на вертикальную шкалу от 0 до 1 и вы увидите, что эти графики почти совпадают на нормальном масштабе отображения.

Comment: @CrazyElf Проблема в том что для этих датасетов  53% это предел обучения. В общем то вопрос в том каков механизм, как возможно улучшение тестовых результатов без улучшения тренировочных?

Comment: Погодите, в заголовке у вас написано, что тестовые данные слишком хорошие. Я что-то уже ничего не понимаю что у вас есть и что вы хотите

Comment: @CrazyElf Хорошие не данные а результаты. Я хотел спросить бывала ли у кого такая картина и из за чего?